# Docker: private registry access

Tags: docker, coreos, docker-registry

I'm trying to push an image to my docker private repository:

```
docker pull busybox
docker tag busybox living-registry.com:5000/busybox
docker push living-registry.com:5000/busybox
```

Docker tells me:

> The push refers to a repository [living-registry.com:5000/busybox]
>   Get https://living-registry.com:5000/v1/_ping: read tcp 195.83.122.16:39714->195.83.122.16:5000: read: connection reset by peer

These commands are being performed on a CoreOS.

In another machine, I've started my registry using this command:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry \
  -v /root/docker-registry/auth:/auth \
  -e "REGISTRY_AUTH=htpasswd" \
  -e "REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM=Registry Realm" \
  -e REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH=/auth/htpasswd \
  -v /root/docker-registry/certs:/certs \
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/registry.crt \
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/registry.key \
  -v /root/docker-registry/data:/var/lib/registry \
  registry:2
```

Everything seems to be right:

```
# netstat -tupln | grep 5000
tcp6       0      0 :::5000       :::*      LISTEN      3160/docker-proxy

# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                          PORTS                    NAMES
27e79f6a504c        registry:2          "/bin/registry serve "   About an hour ago   Restarting (2) 36 minutes ago   0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp   registry
```

So, when I'm trying to log in:

```
[root@jenkins certs]# docker login living-registry.com:5000
Username: xxxx
Password: xxxx
```

> Error response from daemon: Get https://living-registry.com:5000/v1/users/: read tcp 195.83.122.16:39756->195.83.122.16:5000: read: connection reset by peer

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I've already added the certificate (`ca.crt`) in `/etc/ssl/certs` and in `/etc/docker/certs.d/x.x.x.x:5000/`.

From this CoreOS instance, I'm trying to perform that:

`$ docker login https://x.x.x.x:5000
Username: xxx
Password:
Email: xxx@mail.com`

And it tells me:

> Error response from daemon: invalid registry endpoint https://x.x.x.x:5000/v0/: unable to ping registry endpoint https://x.x.x.x:5000/v0/
>   v2 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://x.x.x.x:5000/v2/: EOF
>    v1 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://x.x.x.x:5000/v1/_ping: EOF. If this private registry supports only HTTP or HTTPS with an unknown CA certificate, please add `--insecure-registry x.x.x.x:5000` to the daemon's arguments. In the case of HTTPS, if you have access to the registry's CA certificate, no need for the flag; simply place the CA certificate at /etc/docker/certs.d/x.x.x.x:5000/ca.crt

I've also tried to get the connection directly with `openssl`:

```
openssl s_client -connect x.x.x.x:5000
```

The output is:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
140180300502672:error:140790E5:SSL routines:ssl23_write:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:177:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 308 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1467812448
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Comment: does telnet living-registry.com 5000 work ?

Answer (score 0):

For self-signed certificates, the crt must be copied into

> /etc/docker/cert.d/hostname:port/ca.crt

cf : https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/certificates/

I create certificates :

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 3650d -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /root/docker-registry/certs/registry.key -out /root/docker-registry/certs/registry.crt -days 3650d

cp /root/docker-registry/certs/registry.crt /etc/docker/cert.d/x.x.x.x:5000/ca.crt
```

Comment: This reference documentation is talking about several certiticate files. I've only copied a `registry.crt` file. I'm not able to figure out how should I set this certificate files inside my `/etc/docker/certs.d/x.x.x.x:5000/`. Should I copy the `*.key` file of my `.crt` certificate? (I've added some more details on post).